# Symfony2: how to validate UploadedFile without form?

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-extensions, doctrine-uploadable

I need to <strike>upload</strike> download file from URL to my server and persist it with [Uploadable (DoctrineExtensions)](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/uploadable.md). Almost everything works fine, my approach is:

1. Download file with `curl` to temp folder on my server
2. Create `UploadedFile` method and fill it with property values
3. Insert it to uploadable entity `Media`
4. Do validation
5. Persist and flush

**The simplified code:**

```
// ... download file with curl

// Create UploadedFile object
$fileInfo = new File($tpath);
$file = new UploadedFile($tpath, basename($url), $fileInfo->getMimeType(), $fileInfo->getSize(), null);

// Insert file to Media entity
$media = new Media();
$media = $media->setFile($file);
$uploadableManager->markEntityToUpload($media, $file);

// Validate file (by annotations in entity)
$errors = $validator->validate($media);

// If no errors, persist and flush
if(empty($errors)) {
    $em->persist($this->parentEntity);
    $em->flush();
}
```

If I skip the validation, everything is OK. File is succesfully moved to right path (configured by Uploadable extension in config.yml) and persisted to database. But validation with manualy created `UploadedFile` return this error:

> The file could not be uploaded.

I can disable Validator for upload from URL and validate file with custom method, but doing it with Symfony Validator object would seem to be a cleaner solution to me.

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN the symfony validation component, the constraint UploadedFile internally uses this functin http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-uploaded-file.php

you can see it here https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/File/UploadedFile.php#L213

```
/**
 * Returns whether the file was uploaded successfully.
 *
 * @return bool True if the file has been uploaded with HTTP and no error occurred.
 *
 * @api
 */
public function isValid()
{
    $isOk = $this->error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK;
    return $this->test ? $isOk : $isOk && is_uploaded_file($this->getPathname());
}
```

You will have to create your own Downloadvalidator (yes, you are actually DOWNLOADING the file with curl)

Comment: Can anyone explain how to create this "downloadvalidator" ?

Comment: @ThEBiShOp look here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html